# Eclipse C/C++ error 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm getting these errors in Eclipse when running a simple program.
- I have command line tools installed.
[image: Screen shot of my workspace in Eclipse]

I'm really lost at what to do.  I have been using eclipse for a Java course and then downloaded the C/C++ workstation though having a few issues.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
By the way I'm on Mac latest OS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is likely you have two `main()`s.  What is in your `src` folder?  (Make sure there aren't any other c files compiling with yours.